# react native usememo renderitem not working why?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to prevent unneccessary rerender, so I use useMemo.

But I got this error message:

```
TypeError: renderItem is not a function. (In 'renderItem(props)', 'renderItem' is an instance of Object)
```

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import faker from 'faker';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Advertising = () => {
  const data = [
    { id: '1', name: 'Jens', image: faker.image.avatar() },
    { id: '2', name: 'Günther', image: faker.image.avatar() }
  ];

  const renderItem = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={item => Math.random(100).toString()}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});

export default React.memo(Advertising);
```

......................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Did you try `React.useCallback` instead  of React.useMemo

Answer (score 2):

`useMemo` is a react hook and react hooks can't be used in that way.

I would advice you create a separate component for the this.

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(({item})=>{
   return (<View></View>);
});
```

and then import like so

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return <MyComponent />
}
...
<FlatList 
data={data}
renderItem={renderItem}
keyExtractor={(_item, i)=>i.toString()}
/>
```

Also consider useCallBack

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your renderItem function as a callback inside useMemo.

```
const renderItem = React.useMemo(() => () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
), [data])
```

same as

```
const renderItem = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  </View>
)

const memoizedRenderItem = React.useMemo(renderItem, [data])
```